# InvalidCastException in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have the following source:

```
    private T GetValue<T>(object value)
    {
        return (T)value;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int64 integer = GetValue<Int64>(0);
    }
```

So the constant 0 is an Int32 and has to be cast to an Int64 in the generic method GetValue.
But this will result in an InvalidCastException.

But why?

When I do it with an Int64 as parameter it works fine.

```
    private T GetValue<T>(object value)
    {
        return (T)value;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int64 zero = 0;
        Int64 integer = GetValue<Int64>(zero);
    }
```

Thanks to Jon and Brian.
My final (simplified) solution is like this.

```
    private T GetValue<T>(object value)
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(defaultValue, typeof(T));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int64 integer = GetValue<Int64>(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But why?

Because you're unboxing from a boxed `int` to `long`. It fails in exactly the same way that this fails with no generics:

```
int original = 0;
object boxed = original;
long unboxed = (long) boxed; // Bang!
```

Unboxing conversions *have* to be done to the same type (modulo enums and signed/unsigned).

Comment: Thank you very much. now i use dynamic instead of object and it works.

Comment: @Chris: No, do not use `dynamic` to solve this problem.  In Jon's example you could use `long unboxed = (long) (int) boxed; // Success!` Eric Lippert's excellent explanation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx